# How to add a row in Pyspark that adds up an incremental index?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to automize the return of the 'idx' column incrementally! I had provided how it can be done manually!

```py
schema = StructType([
StructField( 'vin', StringType(), True),StructField( 'age', IntegerType(), True),StructField( 'var', IntegerType(), True),StructField( 'rim', IntegerType(), True),StructField( 'cap', IntegerType(), True),StructField( 'cur', IntegerType(), True)
  ])

data = [['tom', 10,54,87,23,90], ['nick', 15,63,23,11,65], ['juli', 14,87,9,43,21]]
data_1=['sam',60,45,34,12,67]
df=spark.createDataFrame(data,schema)
df=df.withColumn('idx',monotonically_increasing_id()).union(spark.createDataFrame(data_1 ))\
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
#I could do it in this way below , but I want it to be automated!
df=df.withColumn('idx',F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy('age')))\
     .union(spark.createDataFrame([data_1 + [4]] ))
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
df.show()

#Expected outcome:
#>>>
+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| vin|age|var|rim|cap|cur|idx|
+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| tom| 10| 54| 87| 23| 90|  1|
|juli| 14| 87|  9| 43| 21|  2|
|nick| 15| 63| 23| 11| 65|  3|
| sam| 60| 45| 34| 12| 67|  4|
+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the max idx from the original df, and add it to the idx of the new df.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df = df.withColumn('idx',F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy('age')))
df.show()
+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| vin|age|var|rim|cap|cur|idx|
+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| tom| 10| 54| 87| 23| 90|  1|
|juli| 14| 87|  9| 43| 21|  2|
|nick| 15| 63| 23| 11| 65|  3|
+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+

df2 = df.union(
    spark.createDataFrame([data_1], schema).withColumn(
       'idx',
       F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy('age')) + F.lit(df.select(F.max('idx')).head()[0])
    )
)

df2.show()
+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| vin|age|var|rim|cap|cur|idx|
+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| tom| 10| 54| 87| 23| 90|  1|
|juli| 14| 87|  9| 43| 21|  2|
|nick| 15| 63| 23| 11| 65|  3|
| sam| 60| 45| 34| 12| 67|  4|
+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks!, it is throwing an error  : pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`idx`' given input columns: [age, cap, cur, rim, var, vin];;
'Aggregate [max('idx) AS max(idx)#26]
+- LogicalRDD [vin#0, age#1, var#2, rim#3, cap#4, cur#5], false

Comment: the dataframe should have the idx column already, see edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can run again `row_number` after union and update `idx` only if it's null :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data_1 = ['sam', 60, 45, 34, 12, 67]

df = df.withColumn('idx', F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy('age'))) \
    .union(spark.createDataFrame([data_1]).withColumn("idx", F.lit(None))) \
    .withColumn('idx', F.coalesce('idx', F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy('age'))))

df.show()

#+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+
#| vin|age|var|rim|cap|cur|idx|
#+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+
#| tom| 10| 54| 87| 23| 90|  1|
#|juli| 14| 87|  9| 43| 21|  2|
#|nick| 15| 63| 23| 11| 65|  3|
#| sam| 60| 45| 34| 12| 67|  4|
#+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

However, if you add rows with `age < df.age`, you'll need to generate a new row number as you're ordering by `age` column. Otherwise, your column `idx` won't be correct.